# Why can the object be indexed like an array?

Tags: c#, lumenworks

In all the examples I see on the `CsvReader`([link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader#latup)), after reading a record, it is possible to index the `CsvReader` object itself to retrieve a field's value. For example:

```
using (CsvReader csv =
       new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;  //Line X
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(csv[i]));  //Line Y
    }
}
```

Clearly `csv` is an instance of `CsvReader`, whatever type that is.

At Line X, if I try to reference `csv[i]` I get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

At Line Y, I can access `csv[0]` etc. What does the [] mean? Is it not indexing an array?

How can I find out the upper bound of `csv[i]` dynamically as it does not have a `Length` property?

Comment: At line X, `i` is undefined. How can you reference `csv[i]` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an indexer implemented

```
public virtual string this[int field]
{
  get
  {
      return ReadField(field, false, false);
  }
}
```

This is where the exception comes from

```
private string ReadField(int field, bool initializing, bool discardValue)
{
 if (!initializing)
 {
     if (field < 0 || field >= _fieldCount)
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("field", field, 
         string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ExceptionMessage.FieldIndexOutOfRange, field));
 }
```

And it is thrown because without calling `ReadNextRecord _fieldCount` is equal to 0.